# How to muliply array values and store in third array variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two array variables like this

```
$order_qty=array('1','2','3');

$quantity_per_pack= array('50','100','100')
```

I want to multiply these two variables and get stored in third variable which will be in array form such as

```
$total_order_qty = array('50','200','300')
```

*This is my code:*

```
 for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
 {
    $total_order_qty[$i] = $quantity_per_pack[$i]  *  $order_qty[$i] ;
    echo $total_order_qty[$i];
 }
```

I declared these three variables as array before for loop.

Please help me to get solution for this.

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help your

*you can use `array_map` for that like this*

working demo :https://eval.in/1014627

```
function multi($n, $m)
{
   return($n*$m);
}



$order_qty = array('1','2','3');
$quantity_per_pack = array('50','100','100');

$total_order_qty  = array_map("multi", $order_qty, $quantity_per_pack);
print_r($total_order_qty );
```

Program Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 50
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 300
)
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Thank You. Now it's working for me. I took your solution as reference.